# jQuery Datables Regex Search and Listeners

Tags: jquery, datatables, pipe, listeners

I am using jQuery Datatables and I am curious if anyone has run into this issue and a possible native workaround.  When filtering, via the searchbox and using a regex search, I have found a pipe seems to break the listener on the search box.  I currently have a table with several rows.  If I type the following:

add => shows all entries with the string add in it (expected)
build => shows all entries with the string build in it (expected

The listeners works find with looking for one string.  If I type:

add| => the listener appears to break on the pipe.  As in the following:

add|b => takes no action.  (Unexpected)

It continues to only show the results with add.  However, if I backspace after adding the character b (or any character after the pipe) the listener turns back on.  So, if I take the "add|b" backspace over b and then proceed with the second string:

add|build => it works as expected.

I can filter via scripting add|build and it works fine as well.  ie:

```
$("#tblReport_filter").children("label").children("input").attr("value",searched);
```

I have read:

http://datatables.net/development/filtering

and I do understand I can develop a plugin to handle this.  I would like to avoid that if possible.  Has anyone seen the pipe break a (I assume keyup) listener in datatables?  Was there an out of the box way to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: did you get any solution to the problem?